# flash/php game - session management/user identification

Tags: php, flash, session

I have a flash game that requires the user to login. The login system is implemented in flash and sends requests to a php backend that checks if the login information is correct.

I have an idea to return a unique, randomly generated sessionID value whenever a user logs in. Whenever the client sends a request to the server, it will send this sessionID as an identifier. For example, if I assign a user the sessionID '123456', then If the server receives a request 'user:123456, action: bought item X` I will know which user made the request and can update the database accordingly.

When a user logs on again, a different session ID will be generated each time.

I'm wondering if this is a good approach? It would mean everytime a request is received, I would have to search through the user table until I find a match on sessionID. Should I be using php's inbuilt session management?

Comment: Using the PHPs built-in session mgmt will make your life much easier. You can store objects with whatever data is useful to you and make it visible to any part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can send server a request 'user:123456, action: bought item X` . That's unsecure. Use PHP native sessions.

See this [Setting PHP session variables using Flash Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006758/setting-php-session-variables-using-flash-actionscript)

Comment: I'm not sure how php sessions will be more secure? Since they basically do the same thing - send the user a unique random ID and have the user send the ID along with all future requests.

Comment: This seems to be a more secure way http://www.thedbj.com/2010/06/maintaining-sessions-in-actionscript/